# Drawing Animation to Canvas Only When New Frames Are Set?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, requestanimationframe

I have some JavaScript code that uses sprite based animation on the canvas and am trying to see if I can make it more efficient. I'm already using `requestAnimationFrame`, but since it's interaction based I'm also trying to figure out how to get it to only draw frames when a new one is set. However, not matter what I try it still appears to be drawing new frames even when the animation is not running. Sometimes altering the code even seems to increase CPU usage. I'm really confused as to what's going on here.

Here's the original code:

```js
function CanvasSprite(canvas, width, height, sprite_url, rows, columns, total_frames) {
   this.canvas = canvas;
    this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
   this.rows = rows;
 this.columns = columns;
 this.total_frames = total_frames;
 this.frame = 0;

    var scope = this,
     func = function(){
       scope.onSpriteSheet.call(scope);
          }
    this.load('img', 'spritesheet', sprite_url, func);
};

CanvasSprite.prototype.onSpriteSheet = function() {
   this.sw = this.spritesheet.width / this.columns;
   this.sh = this.spritesheet.height / this.rows;
    this.tick(new Date().getTime());
};

CanvasSprite.prototype.load = function(type, prop, url, callback) {
   this[prop] = document.createElement(type);
   this[prop].addEventListener('load', callback);
    this[prop].src = url;
};
 
CanvasSprite.prototype.draw = function() {
 var relativeFrame = Math.round(this.frame * (this.total_frames-1)); 
 var column_frame = relativeFrame % this.columns;
     
   var sx = this.sw * column_frame;
   var sy = this.sh * Math.floor(relativeFrame / this.columns);

 var context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
 context.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
   context.drawImage(this.spritesheet, sx, sy, this.sw, this.sh, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
};
  
CanvasSprite.prototype.tick = function(time) {
      var scope = this,
      func = function(time){
        scope.draw(time || new Date().getTime());
        requestAnimationFrame(func, scope.id);
        //console.log("drawing");
      };
      func();
};

CanvasSprite.prototype.setFrame = function(frame) {
 this.frame = frame;
    //this.tick(new Date().getTime());
    //putting tick() here actually makes it slower :p
};
```

One attempt at modifying it further:

```js
function CanvasSprite(canvas, width, height, sprite_url, rows, columns, total_frames) {
   this.canvas = canvas;
    this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
   this.rows = rows;
 this.columns = columns;
 this.total_frames = total_frames;
    
    this.frameOld = null; //old frame for comparison
 this.frame = 0;

    var scope = this,
     func = function(){
       scope.onSpriteSheet.call(scope);
          }
    this.load('img', 'spritesheet', sprite_url, func);
};

CanvasSprite.prototype.onSpriteSheet = function() {
   this.sw = this.spritesheet.width / this.columns;
   this.sh = this.spritesheet.height / this.rows;
    if(this.frame != this.frameOld) {
        this.tick(new Date().getTime()); //only call tick when new frame differs from old
    };
};

CanvasSprite.prototype.load = function(type, prop, url, callback) {
   this[prop] = document.createElement(type);
   this[prop].addEventListener('load', callback);
    this[prop].src = url;
};
 
CanvasSprite.prototype.draw = function() {
 var relativeFrame = Math.round(this.frame * (this.total_frames-1)); 
 var column_frame = relativeFrame % this.columns;
     
   var sx = this.sw * column_frame;
   var sy = this.sh * Math.floor(relativeFrame / this.columns);

 var context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
 context.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
   context.drawImage(this.spritesheet, sx, sy, this.sw, this.sh, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
};
  
CanvasSprite.prototype.tick = function(time) {
      var scope = this,
      func = function(time){
        scope.draw(time || new Date().getTime());
        requestAnimationFrame(func, scope.id);
        console.log("drawing");
      };
      func();
};

CanvasSprite.prototype.setFrame = function(frame) {
    this.frameOld = this.frame; //update frameOld with previous one
 this.frame = frame; //set new frame
};
```

No matter what I do, the console says it's drawing in sync with the system clock even when I'm not updating frames. CPU profiles reflect this as well. Seems like there's something major I'm missing here. Maybe canvas is already optimizing it behind the scenes so my JS isn't making a difference or only slowing it down with unnecessary logic?

Comment: You can use a `isDirty` flag which is set to true from each call that would alter the frame somehow. Then in the main loop only draw if the flag is true as well as resetting it to false.

Comment: But isn't that just another version of exactly what I'm doing in the second code example? I've tried putting the conditional in the draw loop as well and the results are the same.

Comment: Sorry, scratch that. Comparing to old frames wasn't working, and regardless was horribly inefficient since the values actually often correspond to subframe intervals. Now I'm just trying to figure out where to put my conditional because I can only get it to work inside the actual draw loop, which doesn't improve efficiency since my tick function where I query the system clock and call `requestAnimationFrame` is by far the biggest CPU hog.

Comment: The issue is I have the function that syncs all the animation implemented as a closure...meaning it only gets passed the scope once and therefore isn't receiving updates to the `isDirty` flag. I can't believe I'm actually wishing pointers existed in JS...

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself! First of all, using an `isDirty` flag instead of trying to compare frames. Then since the interaction actually updates the animation in subframe intervals, moved the line that calculates the actual frame to be drawn into the `setFrame` function. Also moved the `tick` function that syncs animation into `setFrame` and used a call to that upon loading to start at frame zero. This way it's not constantly being passed a new date and time  Finally, the conditional to test whether to draw a new frame needs to be inside the closure that calls the draw function. This is because `requestAnimationFrame` is actually a much greater CPU hog than any calls to the canvas.

The result? No CPU usage when it's not being updated and drastically reduced when it is :)

```js
function CanvasSprite(canvas, width, height, sprite_url, rows, columns, total_frames) {
   this.canvas = canvas;
    this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
   this.rows = rows;
 this.columns = columns;
 this.total_frames = total_frames;
    this.isDirty = true;

    var scope = this,
     func = function(){
       scope.onSpriteSheet.call(scope);
          }
    this.load('img', 'spritesheet', sprite_url, func);
};

CanvasSprite.prototype.onSpriteSheet = function() {
   this.sw = this.spritesheet.width / this.columns;
   this.sh = this.spritesheet.height / this.rows;
    this.setFrame(0);
};

CanvasSprite.prototype.load = function(type, prop, url, callback) {
   this[prop] = document.createElement(type);
   this[prop].addEventListener('load', callback);
    this[prop].src = url;
};
 
CanvasSprite.prototype.draw = function() { 
 var column_frame = this.frame % this.columns;
   var sx = this.sw * column_frame;
   var sy = this.sh * Math.floor(this.frame / this.columns);
    
 var context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    context.drawImage(this.spritesheet, sx, sy, this.sw, this.sh, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
};
  
CanvasSprite.prototype.tick = function(time) {
    var scope = this,
    func = function(time){
        if (scope.isDirty) {
            scope.draw(time || new Date().getTime());
            requestAnimationFrame(func, scope.id);
            scope.isDirty = false;
            //only draw to canvas when new frame differs from old
        };
    };
    func();
};

CanvasSprite.prototype.setFrame = function(frame) {
    var tempFrame = Math.round(frame * (this.total_frames-1));;
    if(tempFrame != this.frame) {
        this.frame = tempFrame;
        this.isDirty = true;
        this.tick(new Date().getTime());
    }
};
```